# Root my oreo device?

Tags: rooting, twrp, 8.1-oreo, supersu

I have some experience with rooting, upgrading, installing twrp and another stuff.
My phone is Samsung Galaxy J7+ with (oreo).
Btw, based on some articles that i've read, it's too risky if i want to root my device in os 8.1 (oreo).

And i just want to make sure if i can still make it.

When i'm rooting my device as far as i know, i need twrp (tar files and installing this will need ODIN) and in this case i want to use superSU, bcz i have bad experience with Magisk and anyway i just want superSU. And i don't really remember if installing twrp and rooting my device will cause my internal data to be erased or not.

And i've seen some videos on YT explaining another alternative without twrp, that is using cmd or whatever but please don't suggest me to use this way cz it looks complicated and i doubt if i can do that. Another way is using "KingRoot". But it doesn't work when i tried it on my device with os 7.0 (Nougat). It seems KingRoot only work on the old os?

Back to my main question, So to make it easy, i'll list my questions :

1. Is it possible rooting device with os 8.1 (oreo)?
2. Will my internal data get deleted if i install twrp and root?
3. How to root my device without losing my internal data?

Hope you can help me.

Actually i'm frustated bcz i accidentally deleted some files *a month ago* and lost my important photo. And there is no way except rooting my device to get back my deleted photo.

Comment: 1. yes 2. yes 3. no way

Comment: Installing TWRP is not a technical requirement for rooting but usually the rooting methods are designed to be easily usable through TWRP. Similarly erasing data is not directly related to TWRP or rooting, but unlocking bootloader is usually the prerequisite which erases data (on most of the devices). But the situation vary for different devices, even for same device sometimes. The possibility to root a device usually depends on if the bootloader is unlockable and if the device got community's attention so that TWRP and rooting methods are available.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to root an Android phone without unlocking the bootloader?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218873/is-there-a-way-to-root-an-android-phone-without-unlocking-the-bootloader)

Comment: [Why are the rooting apps like KingRoot not working anymore?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205707/218526)

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3747535