# How to patch and sign android bootloader image to enable "volume_up" button?

Tags: bootloader, root-access

Had trouble with it for a long time because manufacturer disabled the button to unlock the rooting functionality.

Comment: Bootloaders binaries are signed with OEM's private key. You can't sign them. And they are closed-source and highly vendor-specific. There is no general way to patch them.

Comment: I managed to find an answer to the continuation of my question. Which technically removes any reason for this question. Should I answer this question by it or create a new one?

Comment: It'd be better if you post the answer for other's benefit.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Is it really practical to repost info from xda-developers ? It's the post about suboot.sh which works with mtk-su and magiskinit on mtk devices

Comment: You can provide a brief description with link so that answer is not useless if link is dead.

Comment: `fastboot oem key 8` # vol up
`fastboot oem key 2` # vol down `fastboot oem key 5` # power

Comment: @alecxs
`fastboot oem key 8` returns
**FAILED (remote: 'argument size is wrong')**

Comment: seems working for HTC Leo (got it from the mtk-su thread)

Answer (score 0):

I live in the U.S. and what was once the land of the free is now the land of the locked bootloader.  Good luck

https://www.geektrouble.info/explore/android/view/218873

"OEMs/SoC vendors implement a Chain of Trust which must have a hardware-backed root of trust - a cryptographic key. On boot every software component verifies the integrity of the next component before loading it in memory. This chain of trust starts with BootROM (the very first executable code which runs on Power ON) and ends at /system and /vendor partitions. Everything in between - bootloaders, Device Tree, Linux kernel and Android OS code - is verified to be unaltered."

Comment: That's my answer to this question: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218886/218526