# If I generate my own custom key and sign a custom ROM, then will I be able to have root access after locking the bootloader?

Tags: rooting, boot, bootloader, magisk, dm-verity

So what I want to do is boot into my own custom ROM with a locked bootloader. I have a OnePlus 6T so it's possible, but can I have root access after I boot with a locked bootloader? If I replace my custom ROM's boot.img with a patched Magisk boot image, will it be possible to have root access after locking my BL?
Also, will I be able to use TWRP and flash updates through it?

Comment: You question is a bit "misspelled" because with a custom signed system you never get root access but you can sign your apps so that they become system apps. System apps have way more permissions that regular apps, but AFAIK this is not root access (root is even more powerful).

Comment: How will you boot the patched Magisk boot image and TWRP after locking bootloader? Locked bootloader only boots the boot/recovery images signed with OEM's private keys which obviously you don't have. So device won't boot simply. Rooting device with locked bootloader is possible only through some vulnerability.

Comment: See [Is there a way to root an Android phone without unlocking the bootloader?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218873/is-there-a-way-to-root-an-android-phone-without-unlocking-the-bootloader). Same applies to ***Is it possible to lock bootloader after rooting the device?***.

Comment: @IrfanLatif what about CopperOS they do exactly what OP want

Comment: @alecxs hmm CopperHeadOS, which the developer of GrapheneOS claims to be his work. You are talking about [User-settable root of trust](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/device-state#user-settable-root-of-trust) which is one of the main features of AVB (VB2), right? There aren't many devices in my knowledge which support this feature because it's against OEMs' business strategies. Most of the currently available devices have either bootloader unlocking disabled, or is irreversible, or is reversible only with OEM's factory firmware.

Comment: If OP's device (bootloader) supports custom AVB keys, then it's definitely possible to lock bootloader after flashing a (possibly rooted) custom ROM, not CopperHeadOS only but any ROM theoretically. In that case it's a pure development related question.

Comment: @IrfanLatif ah yes, just could far remember that name.. right, that would be developer stuff. i did just read the headline when it came to my mind. Seems the question is completely different from headline and OP is not dev ;) so AVBv2 user-settable root of trust is requirement. that means OnePlus 6T is not supported

Comment: Yeah, you can take a look at https://github.com/chenxiaolong/avbroot and read the documentation carefully.