# How to properly ENABLE dm-verity and FEC for /system on Motorola X4 with LineageOS 17.1?

Tags: lineageos, dm-verity

I have built LineageOS 17.1 for Motorola X4 / payton with unlocked bootloader with reverted commit [81cc203c06596878d2beb62ab6e07f36e278018e](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_kernel_motorola_msm8998/commit/81cc203c06596878d2beb62ab6e07f36e278018e).
The common question is how to disable dm-verity, but I want to know how to properly enable it for /system . The vendor partition is called oem on Motorola.

AVB was deactivated (the device is missing *fastboot flash avb_custom_key* but has a vbmeta_a/b partition?)
During build these options were set:

```
PRODUCT_SUPPORTS_BOOT_SIGNER := true
PRODUCT_SUPPORTS_VERITY := true
PRODUCT_SUPPORTS_VERITY_FEC := true
```

I checked *system.img* and *vendor.img* with verity_verifier script and the *verity_key* and it outputs VERIFIED.
I flashed boot, vendor and system to the corresponding partitions. */verity_key* is inside the *boot.img*. The boot cmdline contains *androidboot.veritymode=eio* and *veritykeyid=id:47b1fe9xxxxxx*. *The boot.img* only contains recovery.fstab, verify option is set there, too. adb enable-verity is succesful for / and for /vendor. */vendor/etc/fstab.qcom* contains the verify option for system and vendor partition.

The following obversations were made:

- During boot I see a message "Verity mode is set to disable". What is this referring to?
- Modifiying data (*touch test*) on the vendor/oem partition from Lineage Recovery results in the errors being corrected by FEC, messages shown from dmesg after next boot:

> ```
> [    3.023786] init: [libfs_mgr]Enabling dm-verity for vendor (mode 0)
> [    3.175842] device-mapper: verity-fec: 259:31: FEC 0: corrected 21 errors
> [    3.257369] device-mapper: verity-fec: 259:31: FEC 4096: corrected 17 errors
> [...]
> ```

The created file *test* vanishes after boot.

- Modifying data on the system partition from Lineage Recovery is not corrected by FEC and no messages show up. The created file *test* is visible on the partition after next boot.
- There is no difference between locked and unlocked bootloader (*fastboot flash lock*).

What am I missing here?

Comment: @alecxs see last paragraph of https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218886/218526

Answer (score 3):

**Warning**! Use at your own risk!
The sense and especially added security of all of this may be disputed. Find some notes about security in the end.

**tl;dr:**

It took me some days to find a solution to get this:

```
[    2.251328] init: init first stage started!
[    2.251561] init: Switching root to '/first_stage_ramdisk'
[    2.252614] init: Using Android DT directory /proc/device-tree/firmware/android/
[    2.603025] init: [libfs_mgr]Enabling dm-verity for system (mode 0)
[    2.603181] init: [libfs_mgr]Verity table: updated block device from '/dev/block/platform/soc/c0c4000.sdhci/by-name/system' to '/dev/block/platform/soc/c0c4000.sdhci/by-name/system_b'
[    2.603195] init: [libfs_mgr]Verity table: updated block device from '/dev/block/platform/soc/c0c4000.sdhci/by-name/system' to '/dev/block/platform/soc/c0c4000.sdhci/by-name/system_b'
[    2.753873] device-mapper: verity-fec: 259:33: FEC 0: corrected 22 errors
[    2.830804] device-mapper: verity-fec: 259:33: FEC 4096: corrected 7 errors
[    2.831080] init: [libfs_mgr]superblock s_max_mnt_count:65535,/dev/block/dm-0
[    2.854916] device-mapper: verity-fec: 259:33: FEC 0: corrected 22 errors
[    2.878336] device-mapper: verity-fec: 259:33: FEC 4096: corrected 7 errors
[    3.001281] device-mapper: verity-fec: 259:33: FEC 1052672: corrected 18 errors
[    3.001825] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: barrier=1
[    3.001947] init: [libfs_mgr]__mount(source=/dev/block/dm-0,target=/system,type=ext4)=0: Success
[    3.002215] init: Switching root to '/system'
[    3.139199] device-mapper: verity-fec: 259:33: FEC 3133440: corrected 12 errors
[    3.272389] init: [libfs_mgr]Enabling dm-verity for vendor (mode 0)
[    3.272662] init: [libfs_mgr]Verity table: updated block device from '/dev/block/platform/soc/c0c4000.sdhci/by-name/oem' to '/dev/block/platform/soc/c0c4000.sdhci/by-name/oem_b'
[    3.272679] init: [libfs_mgr]Verity table: updated block device from '/dev/block/platform/soc/c0c4000.sdhci/by-name/oem' to '/dev/block/platform/soc/c0c4000.sdhci/by-name/oem_b'
[    3.276744] init: [libfs_mgr]superblock s_max_mnt_count:65535,/dev/block/dm-1
[    3.279830] EXT4-fs (dm-1): mounting with "discard" option, but the device does not support discard
[    3.279845] EXT4-fs (dm-1): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: barrier=1,discard
[    3.279935] init: [libfs_mgr]__mount(source=/dev/block/dm-1,target=/vendor,type=ext4)=0: Success
```

- Build LOS 17.1 with the reverted commit from the initial question
- Place verity_key in [ramdisk/first_stage_ramdisk](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/partitions/ramdisk-partitions?hl=en) folder
- Append the following cmdline options, this is the android testing key:

  BOARD_KERNEL_CMDLINE += root=/dev/dm-0 dm=\"system none ro,0 1 android-verity Android:\#7e4333f9bba00adfe0ede979e28ed1920492b40f /dev/block/by-name/system_b\" androidboot.slot_suffix=_b rootwait androidboot.force_normal_boot=1
- Add system partition to the [DTB](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/dto) fstab and include verify option

There are more caveats here than I thought. I will also try to include all words I was searching for in this text.

**Key findings regarding booting and dm-verity about the payton**

- [It seems to be a legacy SAR (system-as-root) device](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/boot.html) (most important read!). The kernel mounts the root/system filesystem itself, no ramdisk or ramdisk partition involved. Typical cmdline arguments for the kernel are *root=/dev/block/mmcblk0p6x*, where x is 5 or 6 for the system A/B partition and init=/init.
- The original motorola files do not contain a fstab in the ramdisk
- There is no system partition defined in the DTB in the motorola files
- Therefore the bootloader seems to verify the boot image, most likely with some certificates baked into the bootloader? (strings -a on the bootloader hints at this). Then it sets the appropriate start partition and maybe the command line for verity verification, more on this later.
- vendor is called oem on motorola.
- Like mentioned the payton is missing *fastboot flash avb_custom_key*, so no new shiny Android Verified Boot (AVB) 2.0 with vbmeta.img. Most likely because it was initially shipped with Android 7.0 and nobody cared updating the structures.

**Some things about building LineageOS 17.1**

- Build LOS like written in [their help](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/payton/build)
- LOS seems to also boot legacy SAR, except when you enter recovery mode.
- Using the instructions below will give you something like Android Verified Boot 1.0
- The build process prepares the following things for [dm-verity](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/dm-verity?hl=en) integration: Creating boot.img, system.img and vendor.img, adds dm-verity metadata to the end of system.img and vendor.img and signs boot.img. vendor is verified in the default LOS configuration by adding it to fstab and additionally creating a DTB fstab entry for it.

**The general build process**

- Codebase is impressively huge: 190 GB without ccache
- Revert the mentioned commit in dm-android-verity.c
- Use the following Kernel cmdline.
- This circumevenes [A/B and slotselect](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/ab/ab_implement) mechanism for selecting the proper system_a or system_b. Without bootloader support I do not know if it is possible to ever reenable A/B.
- Also this configuration always skips recovery, even if you try to boot to recovery from bootloader.
- This did not work with [androidboot.veritykeyid](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/dm-verity?hl=en), I do not know why (yet).
- You have to escape " and # here!

> device/motorola/sdm660-common/BoardConfigCommon.mk:
>
> BOARD_KERNEL_CMDLINE += root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait
> BOARD_KERNEL_CMDLINE += dm=\"system none ro,0 1 android-verity Android:\#7e4333f9bba00adfe0ede979e28ed1920492b40f
> /dev/block/by-name/system_b\"
> BOARD_KERNEL_CMDLINE += androidboot.slot_suffix=_b
> BOARD_KERNEL_CMDLINE += androidboot.force_normal_boot=1
> BOARD_BUILD_SYSTEM_ROOT_IMAGE := false

- without force_normal_boot a "normal" boot goes to recovery.

> kernel/motorola/msm8998/arch/arm/boot/dts/qcom/sdm630.dtsi:
>
> system {
> compatible = "android,system";
> dev = "/dev/block/platform/soc/c0c4000.sdhci/by-name/system";
> type = "ext4";
> mnt_flags = "ro,barrier=1";
> fsmgr_flags = "wait,verify,slotselect"; };

- Maybe you can also leave out the [DTB change](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/dto) (mounting partitions with DTB will be obsolete in Android 11) and use a fstab file (somewhere, maybe in first_stage_ramdisk).
- make sure verity is enabled in ./make/target/product/verity.mk

> PRODUCT_SUPPORTS_BOOT_SIGNER := true
> PRODUCT_SUPPORTS_VERITY := true
> PRODUCT_SUPPORTS_VERITY_FEC := true

- When changing the verity key, do not forget to add it to the kernel in *kernel/motorola/msm8998/certs* and check the certificates in the running system in /proc/keys
- You can get the last (failed) boot messages in */sys/fs/pstore/console-ramoops*
- The resulting system behaves like 2SI ramdisk SAR

**Main Question: Does this add security to the device?**

- You can lock the bootloader afterwards with fastboot flashing lock
- The boot partition has to be verified manually with the key ids shown while booting (at least I think it is some signatures of the signed boot.img)
- Flashing partitions from bootloader does not work
- Entering recovery also does not work
- *fastboot boot file.img* gives an error
- *fastboot flashing unlock* clears userdata, this is good!
- In case anything goes wrong with the running system, you have to clear your device.
- Updating just got a little bit harder without changes to the updater because the A/B partition is hardcoded
- Root needs to be enabled for updates (at least ADB root), so this will stay a userdebug build.
- Changes to */system* can be executed without messing the dm-verity, just sign the changed system.
- dm-verity is in [eio](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/dm-verity?hl=en) mode here, I actually did not try to set it to enforcing.

**Open questions**

- Can you change the kernel cmdline from bootloader?
- Maybe you can blankflash (fastboot oem blankflash) the device, I do not know what happens in this case.

Have fun!