# How to execute Android verified boot during first boot after updating OS in Android

Tags: security, custom-roms, bootloader

I need to execute AVB (Android verified boot) during first boot after updating Android OS. BOARD_AVB_ENABLE = true is already present in the mk file device/hikey/common/BoardConfigCommon.mk in the external/AVB folder.

I want to know how to check if it is detected normally or not.

Execute AVB during first boot after updating OS.

How to detect AVB abnormal / normal detection to AOSP framework?

I am clueless where exactly need to proceed. Kindly guide me.

Reference which I have gone through: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/avb/+/master/README.md

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly ENABLE dm-verity and FEC for /system on Motorola X4 with LineageOS 17.1?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233101/how-to-properly-enable-dm-verity-and-fec-for-system-on-motorola-x4-with-lineage)

Comment: but is this device specific or common for all devices? but how can i trace whether avb is running normally or not? eg: notification to framework? whether avb runs automatically in all devices?

Comment: from logcat dmesg probably