# When is the Final vbmeta Image Generated in a Signed Build?

Tags: lineageos, system, builds

**BACKGROUND**

I am attempting to generate my own signed builds of LineageOS 18.1 and am having trouble with the final signed OTA.  Specifically, the vendor partition is failing during AVB verification which causes a boot loop.

To perform my build, I am following the official Lineage build instructions as well as a number of external guides.  The general outline is as follows:

1. Build Android via `mka target-files-package otatools`.  Interestingly, after this step, I have a valid vbmeta at `$OUT/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/lineage_fajita-target_files-eng.*/IMAGES/vbmeta.img` which has the correct hashes for both the vendor and system images found in the same directory.
2. `./build/tools/releasetools/sign_target_files_apks -o -d $CERTDIR -p "$ANDROID_HOST_OUT" --prebuilts_path $TOPDIR/images/fajita $OUT/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/*-target_files-*.zip signed-target_files.zip` .
3. `./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files -p "$ANDROID_HOST_OUT" -k $CERTDIR/releasekey --block signed-target_files.zip lineage-18.1-$(date "+%Y%m%d")-UNOFFICIAL-fajita-signed.zip`.
4. Profit.

I admit, step 2 confuses me somewhat.  I get that each of the APKs is extracted and signed; that part it easy.  What I do not understand is what happens to the files after they have been signed.  If I extract `signed-target_files.zip` I have both a full system image at `IMAGES/system.img` as well as what appears to be a full system rootfs as individual files at `SYSTEM/*`.  Which is the "correct" system payload?  I notice there is no equivalent `VENDOR/*` directory; shouldn't one have been created in a similar fashion to the system files?

After step 2, I see that the vbmeta image in the extracted `signed-target_files.zip` is different.  Obviously, the hash for the system image has to be regenerated as the image contents have changed and, presumably, the same would have to happen for vendor and/or any other partition which has its contents updated.

Unfortunately, this is where things seem to go off the rails.  Again with the extracted `signed-target_files.zip`:

- `IMAGES/vbmeta.img` has the correct SHA for `IMAGES/system.img`, with a different value from what is found under `$OUT`.
- `IMAGES/vbmeta.img` has an *incorrect* SHA for `IMAGES/vendor.img`.  This value is also different from what is in `$OUT`.
- `IMAGES/vbmeta.img` has correct SHAs for `boot.img` and `dtbo.img` which, as far as I can tell, are unmodified from the original build.

**QUESTIONS**

1. When signing an Android build, which files are used to generate the updated vbmeta image?
2. How do these relate to the contents of `signed-target_files.zip`?
3. Is there any good documentation on the part of the build process?  I have found a bunch of stuff on how APKs are signed or how AVB verification works but, unfortunately, startlingly little on the mechanics of signed image generation itself.

Comment: maybe related [How to properly ENABLE dm-verity and FEC for /system on Motorola X4 with LineageOS 17.1?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233101/how-to-properly-enable-dm-verity-and-fec-for-system-on-motorola-x4-with-lineage)

Comment: Related, but different.  The above question covers how to enable and verify dm-verity across the entire build and boot process.  My question is specifically targeted at the vbmeta regeneration as part of build signing, which isn't discussed in detail in that question.