# Why is it possible to re-lock the bootloader after installing a custom ROM (on some devices)?

Tags: custom-roms, lineageos, bootloader-lock, oneplus-one, fairphone-3

As I understand it, if an Android device’s bootloader is locked (`fastboot oem lock`), it should check the installed system on boot to verify that it’s signed with some (the manufacturer’s?) signing keys. I’ve seen several warnings not to lock the bootloader again after installing a custom ROM like LineageOS because the bootloader would complain about the modified system image and refuse to boot.

However, I have two Android devices on which I have installed custom ROMs:

- The [Fairphone 3 (FP3), where I installed /e/ OS](https://doc.e.foundation/devices/FP3/)
- The [OnePlus One (bacon)](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/bacon), where I installed [LineageOS 18.1 (with microG)](https://download.lineage.microg.org/bacon/)

I’ve subsequently re-locked the bootloader on both devices and, surprisingly, not experienced any issues so far. For the Fairphone 3, I originally assumed that this works because /e/ OS is officially supported by the manufacturer, so I thought that the /e/ OS images are probably signed with some official keys. However, I don’t think there is any such support in the case of the OnePlus One (which is also long out of manufacturer support by now). Another hint is this [forum post on the Fairphone forums](https://forum.fairphone.com/t/official-lineageos-17-1-for-fairphone-3-fairphone-3/66978/70), which reports the following:

> I relocked the bootloader (fastboot flashing lock), it automatically
> wiped my user data, and booted successfully! Also, after restoring my
> data, I was able to upgrade from last-week’s release to the new
> release of today - all without problems.
>
> Now, this does raise a lot of security questions though. I did not
> realize that LineageOS, /e/ and even Fairphone where all signing their
> builds with google test keys - essentially rendering the OS build
> integrity checks meaningless… I guess in fact that means that it
> doesnt really matter which keys are being used, as they are simply not
> checked? Any key would be accepted?

So, my question is: Why does running /e/ OS or LineageOS with a locked bootloader work in these cases? What is the significance of the Google test keys here – do the bootloaders just always accept them?

Comment: May be because some new devices support [user-settable root of trust](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/device-state#user-settable-root-of-trust). Details here: [Is there a way to root an Android phone without unlocking the bootloader?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218886/218526).

Comment: @IrfanLatif Ah, interesting! However, since you say “new devices”, this doesn’t sound like it would have been available at the time when the OnePlus One was released (2014)? I also don’t understand how it fits in with the statement about the Google test keys.

Comment: The official LOS subreddit has a comprehensive [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/n7yo7u/a_discussion_about_bootloader_lockingunlocking/) on this topic. Still I'd advise against it because it makes recovering from failures much harder.

Comment: @AndyYan Thanks, that was a very helpful and detailed overview. I would say the most relevant part is: _There are also a few phones (like the original Pixel/XL and OnePlus phones like the 5/5t and older) that don't support AVB v2, but can have their bootloaders relocked because they simply *never* check to see if the OS is signed by the vendor, just that it has some valid signature on it._ This implies that the OnePlus One doesn’t check the origin of the signature, explaining that case. I suppose the Fairphone 3 is a similar case, then?

Comment: so in essence, re-locking does not make sense, because in the few models where it does work, it gets you no extra security, and otherwise just breaks your boot