# How to secure an unlocked Bootloader after installing custom ROM?

Tags: custom-roms, fastboot, bootloader, bootloader-lock

To install a custom ROM, we obviously need an **unlocked bootloader**. But after installing a custom ROM, is there any way to **password protect** or **secure** the bootloader so that if the phone gets stolen or someone bad gets had on the phone for a while, they can't wipe all data from the phone?

I am not worried about data getting leaked as I use encryption. Moreover, password protecting the recovery doesn't help as `fastboot` can wipe the recovery in seconds.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If your device supports user settable root of trust re-locking is an option, however you really have to be sure what you are doing as relocking the bootloader has a high chance to brick your device if something is not correct. read also https://android.stackexchange.com/q/238980/2241 and the comments.

Comment: @Robert yeah re-locking after installing custom ROM and recovery is risky. But, is there any way to password protect the bootloader?

Comment: nothing prevents factory reset