# Must a device's bootloader be unlocked to temporarily boot into another recovery?

Tags: fastboot

If I want to boot into a temporary recovery by issuing command

```
fastboot boot my_temp_recovery.img
```

must the bootloader of the device first be unlocked?

Comment: A locked bootloader boots a `boot.img` (or `recovery.img`) only if it's signed with OEM's private keys: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218886/218526

Comment: @alecxs It depends on the OEM. I had a Nokia device which used to boot `boot.img` from factory firmware. Never tested with any other device because the very first thing after having a device is bootloader unlocking ;)

Answer (score 0):

It does indeed look like an unlocked bootloader is a requirement even for temporary boots, the key message found is the **`Device not unlocked cannot boot`**

```
$fastboot boot twrp.img
Sending 'boot.img' (15240 KB)            OKAY [  0.510s]
Booting                                  FAILED (remote: '    Device not unlocked cannot boot')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

```
$fastboot oem device-info
(bootloader)    Device tampered: true
(bootloader)    Device unlocked: false
(bootloader)    Charger screen enabled: false
(bootloader)    Display panel:
OKAY [  0.000s]
Finished. Total time: 0.000s
```